# SQL Server: Queries order C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a form, the user need to fill it out.
I need to do 3 things:

1. check if the UserEmail exist in database
2. if UserEmail exist then Update the information like Name, Phone, etc.
3. but if UserEmail does not exist then create a new User in the db.

I would like to ask you guys whats the proper way to do it.
This is what I did so far:

```
    protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
    Conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite41\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand SQLcmd = new SqlCommand();
    SQLcmd.Connection = Conn;
    //SQLcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Phone, Email, Adress) VALUES ('"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtPhone.Text+"','"+txtEmail.Text+"','"+txtAdress.Text+"')";
    SQLcmd.CommandText = "SELECT Email FROM Customers";
    Conn.Open();
    var Email = SQLcmd.ExecuteScalar();
    lblMessage.Text = "";
    if (Email.ToString() == txtEmail.Text)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Email already exist! - so far so good";
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
    }
    Conn.Close();
}
```

So now how should I proceed with the other queries?

Comment: Use `WHERE` clause to check your input exist in your `Email` table like `WHERE Email = @email`. If it is exist, update it's `Name`  and `Phone` in your database in if statement. It it is not exist, `INSERT` a new user with it's information in your else part.

Comment: Can you please give me an example, show it by code?

Comment: A single [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement can be written that does the complete job. When it comes to SQL, you shouldn't try to break things down into a series of steps - tell the system what you want and let it work out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a Procedure for this Pass your all parameters to the Procedure Like FirstName,LastName,email,PhoneNo etc.
the Procedure will check IF Email exists or not based on email it will Insert or Update your data .
procedure code like this ..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateCustomerInfo @firstName VARCHAR(50)
    ,@LastName VARCHAR(50)
    ,@email VARCHAR(50)
    ,@Phone VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM CUSTOMERMASTER
            WHERE Email = @email
            )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE CUSTOMERMASTER
        SET FirstName = @firstName
            ,LasstName = @LastName
            ,Telephone = @Phone
        WHERE Email = @email
    END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMERMASTER (
            FirstName
            ,LastName
            ,Email
            ,Telephone
            )
        VALUES (
            @firstName
            ,@LastName
            ,@email
            ,@Phone
            )
END
```

Comment: you mean like a function?